# How come does this Expo bare workflow project run in Expo Go app?

Tags: react-native, expo

https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/tree/master/react-native/image-classification/expo

This project does come with both Android and iOS folders, which should mean this is not an Expo-managed workflow, but a bare one. So my question is how come it runs in Expo Go app both on Android and iOS (using: yarn start) without having to first make a dev-build as is the case with bare workflows (using: eas build --profile development --platform all -> expo start --dev-client). What am I missing in understanding the process? Thank you.

Comment: I recall hearing that you can still run ejected expo apps with the Expo Go client, but any Native modules that expo doesnt cover wouldnt be supported

Comment: Here it says that Expo Go can be used to run most react native projects if you create fallback components for the native modules Expo Go doesnt support https://docs.expo.dev/bare/using-expo-client/#runtime-detection